# How can I change the default PopupMenu's text color?

Tags: flutter

I have a `MaterialApp` with `TextField`s, and they have the default popup menu (with items "cut", "copy" and "paste").

My problem is: Their text color is always white - so the items are all invisible because my background is also white!

How can I change the text color of the popup items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the culprit: My ButtonTheme defined a `colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark()`, which made the button text white. Removing the colorScheme line let the button text be black again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case only helped to change the brightness of the Theme to Brightness.light

But be ready for number of UI changes after changing app's main theme...